# How can I access a variable outside function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I access to a variable outside function next.js i want to get
name outside the data

```
let getDetail = async () => {
    let body = { 
      code: '12',
      provider: 'bb', 
      
    };
     let { data } = await Axios.post(
      "https://blbla",
      JSON.stringify(body)
    );   
      let { name } = data;
      
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You could return name,

```
let { name } = data;
return name;
```

and then when you call the function, if you need the name, you could say:

```
name = getDetail();
```